# Galaxy Grand i9082 how to remove stability update package file

Tags: ota-update, stock-rom, samsung-galaxy-grand

Hii everyone yesterday night i flashed stock JellyBean 4.2.2 ROM using odin tool and i kept WiFi on whole night for restoring apps but unexpectedly 198.59 MB stability update package as downloaded (Which is the root cause for all the hang issues in device ) and it is showing popup for every 3 hours to install the package. please tell me whether there is any possibility to remove the stability update file from device before installing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix up the issue by clearing Software Update data. Go to Settings --> More --> Application Manager --> All Applications --> Software Update --> clear data

and then i turned off software update